How to adjust touch sensitivity using @hello-pangea/dnd (formerly react-beautiful-dnd)
I'm making a draggable list with hello-pangea/dnd, which works well for web, but on mobile, you have to touch an item for a bit before it registers. Is there a way to make it more sensitive? I've googled and asked chatgpt, but no luck. Thank you!
I tried using onTouchStart to cause an onMouseDown event, but that didn't do anything. It's still the case that starting to swipe the list item doesn't register as a touch.
onTouchStart={(e) => provided.dragHandleProps.onMouseDown(e)}

const onDragStart = (e) => {
    // Custom logic to control sensitivity
    if (e.touches.length === 1) {
      // Handle touch start behavior
    }
  };

  

